# Bedeutet "etwas anschauen" das gleiche wie "zu etwas sehen"?

Tags: difference, semantics

Bedeutet "etwas anschauen" das gleiche wie "zu etwas sehen / schauen"?

z.B.:

> Ich habe den Baum angeschaut.

vs.

> Ich sah zu dem Baum.

Answer (score 5):

"Ja" - in beiden Fällen wird geguckt/ ist der Baum der Grund des Guckens.

"Nein" - der kleine Unterschied liegt im Detail:

> Ich habe den Baum angeschaut = ich habe ihn bewusst betrachtet.

Z.B. wegen seiner Form, Farbe, Standort, Umgebung, ... - irgendwas war wichtig an diesem Baum, dass ich mir gemerkt habe / sehen sollte.

Im Gegesatz dazu:

> Ich sah zu dem Baum = Ich habe in die Richtung des Baumes geschaut.

D.h., es war wichtig, in diese Richtung zu sehen und der Baum ist nur die Richtungsangabe. Daher auch der Dativ. Die (anderen) Eigenschaften des Baumes sind in diesem Satz unwichtig.

Comment: Ich würde das *Jain* weglassen. Der Unterschied ist ja nicht so winzig, dass er zu vernachlässigen wäre.

Comment: @Olafant: danke für den Hinweis, habe es erklärt.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich habe den Baum angeschaut.

Der Baum ist das **direkte Objekt** der Betrachtung. (den - Akkusativ)

> Ich sah zu dem Baum.

Ich sehe nur in die Richtung des Baumes. Der Baum ist **indirektes Objekt**. (dem - Dativ)

Comment: 'zu dem Baum' ist nicht direktes Objekt, sondern adverviale Ergänzung.

Comment: @multiplexetliber 'zu dem Baum' *ergänzt* also. Interessant! Es geht hier um Semantik und das Objekt *der Betrachtung*.

Comment: Die Frage nach semantischen Feldern ist unabhängig von der Funktion von Elementen im Satz. Dativobjekte zeichnen sich u.a. dadurch aus, dass sie **nie** eine Präposition bei sich haben können: Ich helfe meinem Bruder. (Wem?) Präpositionalobjekte haben grundsätzlich **immer** eine Präposition: Ich spreche mit meinem Bruder. (Mit wem?). Aber: Ich gehe zur Post (Adv. Erg.; wohin?). Analog: Ich schaue zu dem Baum. Dass der Baum der log. Gegenstand, das log. Ziel, das log. 'Objekt' des Betrachtens ist, macht ihn noch lange nicht zum gramm. Objekt. ...

Comment: ... Aber du darfst mir gerne die Stelle z.B. bei Eisenberg oder Helbig nennen, die beweist, dass du recht hast. Falls dir der Terminus 'Adv. Erg.' nicht gefällt, 'Adverbialbestimmung' geht auch.

Answer (score 1):

> Bedeutet "etwas anschauen" das gleiche wie "zu etwas sehen / schauen"?

Nein, es ist nicht die gleiche Bedeutung.

Nur *hinsehen* ist semantisch etwas schächer als *anschauen*.
Letzteres meint schon eher eine genauere Betrachtung des Gegenstands.

Hier zwei andere Beispiele:

> Ich hörte die Blätter rascheln und sah (reflexartig) zu dem Baum.

vs.

> Ich habe mir diesen besonderen Baum ganz genau angeschaut, ich bin mir sicher was die Anomalie im Wuchs verursacht hat.