# Was ist Unterschied zwischen sehen, ansehen, gucken und schauen?

Tags: difference, verb, learning, low-german

Ich möchte wissen, was das Unterschied zwischen *sehen*, *ansehen*, *gucken* und *schauen* ist.
Sind all diese Verben equivalent?
Kann man das irgendwann und in jeder Situation benutzen?
Geben Sie mir bitte Beispiele!

Comment: Verwandt (engl.): https://german.stackexchange.com/q/49843/25241

Comment: Ebenso verwandt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50050/bedeutet-etwas-anschauen-das-gleiche-wie-zu-etwas-sehen/50051#50051

Answer (score 11):

Ein Problem bei der Unterscheidung ist die regionale Variation im Gebrauch dieser Verben:

- **schauen** ist eher süddeutsch; nach dem Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache benutzt man es häufig in Franken, Bayern und Österreich.
- **gucken** ist ebenfalls regional; laut dem Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache spricht man es so in Sachsen und Thüringen, in Hessen, Rheinland-Pfalz und Württemberg.
- In meiner Region (Westdeutschland, Ruhrgebiet) wird es ***kucken*** gesprochen, aber meistens *gucken* geschrieben. Inzwischen gibt es die Variante *kucken* auch im Duden als 'norddeutsch'; der Atlas der Alltagssprache nennt es für NRW, Niedersachsen, Schleswig-Holstein, Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Brandenburg und den nördlichen Teil von Sachsen-Anhalt.
- Von allen drei Basisverben gibt es eine Serie von Zusammensetzungen, sowohl nicht trennbare Präfixverben (beschauen, ersehen, sich in jemanden vergucken) als auch trennbare Partikelverben (anschauen, ansehen, angucken / wegsehen, wegschauen, weggucken ... und viele weitere).
- [In der deutschsprachigen Schweiz, im Elsass und im alemannisch-sprachigen Gebiet West-Österreichs gibt es das regionale '*luege*'.]

Nach meinem Eindruck lassen sich die Gebrauchsunterschiede hier weniger über die Bedeutung fassen als über die Zahl und Art der syntaktischen Mitspieler im Satz:

> **etwas/jemanden sehen** bezieht sich je nach Kontext meist auf einen größeren Zusammenhang, der mitverstanden wird: *Ich habe sie in der Stadt gesehen* = *'unverabredet getroffen und möglicherweise ein paar Worte mit ihr gewechselt'* oder bei Kindern, die eigentlich in der Schule sein sollten = *'sie haben die Schule geschwänzt'*; die Frage *hast du die Wohnung denn auch gesehen?* bedeutet '*warst du auch wirklich drin und hast dir ein Bild gemacht?*'; *ich hab die Sendung auch gesehen* = '*wir haben den gleichen Informationsstand, wir können darüber reden.*'
>
> **etwas sehen** heißt vorrangig auch, dass etwas in mein Blickfeld geraten ist, ohne dass ich das beabsichtigt habe: *Hast du auch den Unfall gesehen?* Ein Quasi-Synonym dafür wäre *'etwas mitbekommen'* oder '*Zeuge sein von'*.
>
> **etwas sehen** oder **sehen, dass** heißt unter anderem auch *'etwas verstehen'* oder *'etwas einsehen'*: *Ich habe gesehen, dass das Projekt in der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht zu schaffen war.*

Weitere typische Kontexte sind:

- **nach jemandem/etwas sehen** = 'einen Blick werfen auf': *Kannst du mal nach den Kindern sehen, ob sie schon schlafen? / Kannst du mal nach der Heizung sehen? Irgendwas stimmt da nicht.* [auch als *nach etwas gucken/schauen*]
- **nach jemandem sehen** = 'vorbeischauen bei, ob alles in Ordnung ist': *Kannst du am Wochenende mal nach der Oma sehen? Sie klang am Telefon etwas deprimiert.* [hier auch *gucken/schauen*]
- **an etwas etwas (anderes) sehen** = 'erkennen': *Der Arzt hat an der Rötung gesehen, dass ich einen Zeckenbiss hatte*. [Hier sind *gucken/schauen* nicht möglich.]
- **sich sehen** kann heißen 'zu Gesicht bekommen': *Wir sehen uns nur alle drei Wochen, weil wir zu unterschiedlichen Zeiten arbeiten.* [hier ebenfalls kein *gucken/schauen* möglich]
- **sich sehen** heißt auch 'sich treffen': *Wir sehen uns heute Abend.* [*gucken/schauen* nicht möglich]
- **sich sehen lassen** = '(zu Besuch) kommen': *Lass dich mal wieder bei uns sehen!* In dieser Kombination sagt man auch *sich blicken lassen*. [aber nicht *'sich gucken/schauen lassen']
- **etwas von irgendwoher sehen können** = 'von irgendwoher zu erblicken sein': *Man kann bei schönem Wetter von Konstanz aus den Säntis sehen.* [hier auch *schauen* möglich (?), *gucken* nicht]
- **etwas nicht mehr sehen können** = 'genug haben von / einer Sache überdrüssig sein': *Nach dem Film über die Tierhaltung kann ich kein Fleisch mehr sehen.* [nicht mit *gucken/schauen*]
- **etwas irgendwie sehen** = 'eine bestimmte Meinung zu etwas haben': *Ich sehe das anders als du. / Ich sehe die Sache kritisch.* [*gucken/schauen* hier nicht möglich]
- **jemanden etwas tun sehen** (*er sah die Leute arbeiten*) oder **etwas geschehen sehen** (*er sah den Baum fallen*) ist ein syntaktischer Spezialfall von *sehen*; diese Konstruktion mit
  Ersatzinfinitiv '*sehen*' für das eigentlich zu erwartende Partizip 2
  ist bei *gucken/schauen* nicht möglich.
- Das Gleiche gilt für ein reflexiv gebrauchtes **sich sehen (können)** in Fällen wie '*sich im Spiegel sehen*' - *gucken/schauen* ist hier nicht möglich.

Bei gründlicher Suche wird man wohl mindestens 100 weitere Kontexte mit weiteren Bedeutungsvarianten finden, die häufig vorkommen, vor allem auch im Bereich der Redewendungen.

> **etwas ansehen** heißt vor allem 'etwas gezielt und absichtlich in den Blick nehmen': *Der Polizist sah den Mann an.* In diesem Kontext heißt es speziell 'er richtete den Blick auf ihn' oder 'er sah ihm ins Gesicht'.

- Alltagssprachlich häufig ist die Kombination **sich (Dativ) etwas ansehen** = eine längere Zeit sehend oder lesend mit etwa beschäftigt sein: *sich einen Film ansehen, sich die Schaufenster ansehen, sich den Gesetzentwurf ansehen*; auch als 'etwas kontrollieren', ähnlich wie *'nach etwas sehen'*: *Ich hab mir die Waschmaschine angesehen - alles in Ordnung.*
- **jemandem etwas ansehen** = z.B. sehen, dass jemand lügt oder dass dem anderen etwas peinlich ist: *Ich habe ihm angesehen, dass ihm die ganze Geschichte sehr unangenehm war.*
- **jemandem ist etwas anzusehen** in ähnlicher Bedeutung: *Die Anstrengung der letzten Woche war ihm deutlich anzusehen.*
- **jemanden irgendwie ansehen** = 'eine bestimmte Art von Blick auf jemanden richten': *Der Richter sah den Jugendlichen prüfend / scharf / wohlwollend an.*
- **etwas ist irgendwie anzusehen** = ein schöner / netter / furchtbarer Anblick: *Es war schrecklich (das mit) anzusehen.*
- **sich jemanden ansehen** = 'testweise einstellen, auf Probe beschäftigen': *Wir sehen uns neue Leute erst mal ein paar Tage an, bevor wir mit ihnen über einen Arbeitsvertrag sprechen.*
- **etwas / jemanden ansehen als** = 'halten für' / 'betrachten als': *Ich sehe das als ein ernstes Problem an.* [Umgangssprachlich kann man hier auch 'sehen' ohne 'an-' sagen: *Ich sehe das als Problem.*]

Auch hier gibt es eine Vielzahl weiterer möglicher Kontexte mit etlichen Bedeutungsvarianten, vermutlich nicht so viele wie bei '*sehen*'.

> Umgangssprachliches **gucken** (kucken, berlinisch 'kieken') ist in meiner Region (Westdeutschland) vor allem ein zeitlich begrenztes zielgerichtetes Hinschauen. In Süddeutschland (auch in Österreich und teilweise in der Schweiz) entspricht dem **schauen**, weswegen die beiden hier zusammen vorgestellt werden.

- **irgendwohin gucken** (kucken)/**schauen** bezeichnet die Blickrichtung: *auf den Monitor / jemandem ins Gesicht / zu jemandem herüber- / aufs Wasser / auf die Wand / nach oben gucken/schauen* [das alles auch mit *sehen*, teilweise eher mit *blicken*, *starren* oder mit Präfixverben (*aufs Wasser hinausblicken*)]
- Auch für ein fokussiertes / scharf gestelltes Hinsehen sagt man **irgendwohin gucken/schauen**: *auf seine Fingernägel / auf die Liste der Inhaltsstoffe im Joghurt gucken/schauen* (allerdings heißt es bei mir in Westdeutschland eher '*sich etwas (genau) ansehen'*); ebenso für ein interessiertes Sich-Ansehen: *Fernsehen gucken* (bei uns der gesprochen-sprachliche Standardausdruck), im Süden *Fernsehen schauen*; *drei Stunden Fußball gucken/schauen; in die Bücher gucken/schauen* (= '*lernen*'); *in den Rückspiegel / bei jemandem durchs Fenster gucken/schauen* [Hier ist *sehen* prinzipiell ebenfalls möglich - bis auf '*Fernsehen sehen' -, aber mit Abstufungen bei der Üblichkeit.]
- Ebenso nimmt man für ein heimliches / unerlaubtes Zusehen das Verb **(irgendwoher / irgendwo durch / irgendwohin) gucken/schauen** (kucken) = 'lugen', 'spähen': *durch den Türspalt / durchs Schlüsselloch gucken, über den Blattrand einer Zeitung / Rand der Brille gucken/schauen, bei den Nachbarn in die Schränke / in die Töpfe gucken/schauen, einer Frau unter den Rock / auf den Hintern gucken/schauen, jemandem in die Karten gucken/schauen* [auch hier *sehen* grundsätzlich möglich, aber nicht üblich]
- **irgendwie (mit einem bestimmten Gesichtsausdruck) gucken(kucken)/schauen** = 'ein Gesicht machen, das auf die Seelenverfassung schließen lässt': *traurig / böse / komisch gucken/schauen* (= irgendwie irritiert oder schwer definierbar), *blöd gucken* (= verständnislos, auch in schadenfrohen Kommentarsätzen wie '*ja, da kuckst du jetzt blöd!*' mit der Nebenbedeutung '*tja, Pech gehabt, mein Lieber, ist halt dumm für dich gelaufen…*'), auch redensartlich als '*dumm aus der Wäsche gucken/schauen*'; dies ist teilsynonym mit *'glotzen' / 'stieren'*. [hier *sehen* nicht möglich]
- **gucken (kucken) dürfen** oder **jemanden gucken (kucken) lassen** bedeutet, dass *jemand* längere Zeit *bei etwas zugucken (zukucken)/zuschauen* = Zuschauer sein *darf*, zur Unterhaltung oder um sich etwas '*abzugucken*' (abzukucken)/'*abzuschauen*', damit derjenige es später nachmachen kann: *Ich durfte immer gucken, wenn bei uns im Haus etwas repariert wurde, da hab ich viel gelernt.* (Ob man das so auch mit schauen sagen kann?: ?*Ich durfte immer schauen, wenn...*) [hier alternativ *zusehen/zuschauen/zugucken*, aber nicht *sehen* blanko]
- **irgendwo gucken/schauen** (stark umgangssprachlich) = suchen: *da musst du mal im Internet gucken/schauen; hast du auch überall geguckt? (?geschaut >* eher *'nachgeschaut'); ich hab in drei Wörterbüchern geguckt* (= nachgesehen); *guck/schau mal auf dem Schreibtisch, da liegt der Schlüssel*. [*sehen* nicht möglich]
- **guck/schau mal (hier)!** (kuck mal) bzw. *kannst du mal kurz gucken (kucken)/schauen* ist die '*Aufforderung*' an einen anderen, sich etwas anzusehen; es ist nach DWDS die häufigste Wortverbindung für *gucken (kucken)*. [*sehen* hier wieder im Prinzip möglich, aber unüblich]
- **mal gucken/schauen** (stark umgangssprachlich) heißt aber auch: 'sehen, was man tun kann, etwas vage in Aussicht stellen' (bzw. durch die Blume sagen, dass man nichts unternehmen wird): *Der Strom in der Wohnung läuft wieder, und wegen / mit der feuchten Wand gucken/schauen wir mal. / ich guck/schau mal und melde mich dann.* [*sehen* so nicht möglich]

> Abweichend zu *gucken/kucken*gilt für '*schauen*':

- **irgendwie (Gesichtsausdruck) schauen** bezeichnet die anscheinende Stimmung der schauenden Person: ungläubig / böse / finster schauen: Er schaute gelangweilt. DMDS bezeichnet diesen Gebrauch als *gehoben, süddeutsch, österreichisch*. Ohne Lokalergänzung ist das in meiner Region (auch mit 'kucken') möglich, erscheint mir aber nicht sehr üblich (aber: *Was guckst du so böse?*), wir würden stattdessen schreiben 'er machte ein ungläubiges / finsteres Gesicht' oder sagen 'er sah traurig/böse aus'.
- Formelhaftes bzw. redensartliches **schauen, dass** oder **schauen, wie** (oft imperativisch) bedeutet eine 'dringende Aufforderung' (*schau, dass du rechtzeitig fertig wirst*) oder '(angestrengt) versuchen' (*ich musste allein schauen, wie damit fertig werde*). Ein mögliches Synonym wäre im Imperativ '*mach, dass (du hier wegkommst)*', in meiner Region meist als 'sieh zu': *Sieh zu, dass die Post heute noch rausgeht. / Sieh zu, wie du alleine klarkommst. *Gucken/kucken* passt hier nicht.
- Im Unterschied zu gucken kann **etwas schauen** (mit einem Akkusativobjekt) jedoch auch so etwas wie 'erschauen' bzw. 'mit seinem inneren Auge erfassen' bedeuten, in älterer Sprache auch 'etwas erkennen' oder 'einer Sache inne werden': "*Selig sind die reines Herzens sind / denn sie werden Gott schauen.*" / "*alles das hatte einen Einfluß auf die Empfindungen, mit denen ich diesen Inbegriff der Schönheit schaute.*" (Wilh. Bölsche, Das Liebesleben in der Natur, 1900). Ein solcher Gebrauch wäre heute veraltet oder wirkte philosophisch, vielleicht esoterisch, romantisch-poetisch oder eigenwillig – jedenfalls fremd.

...

Für einen Deutschlerner ist vor allem interessant, ob die Verben untereinander austauschbar sind. Das wegen der regionalen Gebrauchsunterschiede schwer zu fassen:

- 'Ansehen' hat eine integrierte Präposition (ursprünglich ein Adverb) und verhält sich syntaktisch anders. Für 'sich etwas ansehen' passt keins der anderen Verben (*ich hab mir den Film im Fernsehen gesehen / geschaut / geguckt). Man kann aber sagen: Ich hab mir den Film im Fernsehen angeschaut / angeguckt!
- 'Schauen' kann man nicht im Sinne von 'registrieren'/'mitbekommen' benutzen, obwohl 'schauen' in vielen Fällen mit 'sehen' austauschbar ist. Es ist also falsch, zu sagen: *Ich habe nicht geschaut, wie die alte Frau hingefallen ist. Der Grund ist, dass 'schauen' sich heutzutage nicht beliebig mit einem Akkusativ als 'wahrgenommenem Objekt' verbinden lässt: *Ich habe das Buch geschaut, es lag auf der Fensterbank. Akzeptierte Akkusativobjekte für 'schauen' sind Fernsehsendungen, Videos, Filme oder bestimmte Programme oder Youtube-Kanäle oder Streamingdienste, wobei man deren Status als Objekte wie bei *Auto fahren* in Frage stellen kann; eher sind es so etwas wie Präfixe, die mit dem Verb zusammen ein integriertes Prädikat bilden und daher auch keinen Artikel haben: *drei Stunden Youtube schauen (gucken), den ganzen Tag Fußball schauen (gucken)*.
- Das 'wahrgenommene Objekt' wird bei '*sehen*' im Grundsatz akkusativisch angeschlossen (ich habe den Film gesehen), bei '*gucken/schauen*' als Lokalergänzung, meist zu verstehen als Richtungsergänzung (sehr aufs Geld gucken = sparen müssen; zur Tafel / nach vorne schauen). Bei '*ansehen*' ist ein Akkusativobjekt möglich, eine Lokalergänzung nicht möglich, im täglichen Gebrauch in meiner Region ist es meist reflexivisch konstruiert (ich hab mir heute drei Wohnungen angesehen).
- Bei Videomaterial, Filmen und dergleichen wird man eher von '*sehen*' reden, bei Printmaterial eher von 'sich ansehen' oder 'lesen': *Ich hab gestern sein Video gesehen.*/*Ich hab mir sein Referat gestern angesehen.* - *Ich hab das Manuskript gesehen* würde ich eher verstehen als '*ich habe es irgendwo herumliegen sehen*' oder '*es scheint fertig zu sein, denn er hat es mir ausgedruckt gezeigt*'. Man sagt allerdings auch *ich hab mir sein Video angesehen* für 'zu Gemüte geführt'.
- 'Guck mal', 'schau mal' und 'sieh mal' können alle drei in einer Kommunikation als eine Einladung zum Perspektivwechsel (= aber überleg auch mal von der anderen Seite her) benutzt werden: '*Du hast natürlich recht, das muss alles gründlich geprüft werden, aber schau auch mal, wie wenig Zeit uns noch bleibt*.' Die Entscheidung für ein bestimmtes Verb fällt hier nach individuellen, regionalen und stilistischen Präferenzen - 'schau mal' wäre für mich eher ein 'inneres Sehen' und hier am besten passend, 'sieh mal' empfinde ich als 'gehoben' und 'kuck mal' hier deutlich umgangssprachlich.

(Vorläufig fertig, Nachtrag von Einzelfällen möglich).

Comment: 1+. Ist schon jetzt eine richtig gute Antwort!

Comment: vielleicht noch erwähnen, dass "gucken/kucken" umgangssprachlich ist

Comment: Viele Verwendungen von "schauen" sind mit "hinsehen" austauschbar. Wenn nicht, dann ist das oft, weil statt "schauen" auch eine Präfixvariante verwendbar wäre, also "Video schauen" = "Video anschauen", "komisch schauen" = "komisch dreinschauen". Bin nicht sicher, ob das eine allgemeingültige Regel ist.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl: Für 'hinsehen' im Sinne von 'hinschauen' würden wir eher 'hinkucken' sagen (jetzt kuck ma richtig hin!). 'Wir haben Videos angeschaut' würde man bei uns nicht sagen, sondern 'wir haben uns Videos angesehen'. 'Komisch dreinschauen' wäre für mich schrift-/literatursprachlich. Die Sache mit den Präfixverben und deren Weglassung ist ein Kapitel für sich. Aber stimmt: Die Beziehungen dieser Solo-Verben zu ihren Präfix-Abkömmlingen sind stark; die Präfixverben formen die Bedeutungen der  Ausgangsverben stark mit, teilweise übernehmen die Basisverben die Bedeutung ihrer Ableitungen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Ist vermutlich eine österreichische Sache. "Hinkucken" würde ich einfach nie sagen. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Im Grunde sind sehen, ansehen, gucken und schauen laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sehen) synonym zueinander.

Im täglichen Gebrauch würde man das wohl wie folgt definieren:

- sehen: "mit den Augen optische Eindrücke wahrnehmen"  ([Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sehen))
- ansehen: "den Blick auf jemanden, etwas richten; ins Gesicht blicken, betrachten" ([Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ansehen))
- gucken: "seine Blicke auf ein bestimmtes Ziel richten" ([Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gucken))
- schauen: komplett synonym zu sehen ([Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schauen))

Das meint alles im Groben wirklich das Selbe und wird auch im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nicht wirklich stark differenziert.

Als bestes Beispiel:

- "Kannst du nach den Kindern **sehen**?
- "Kannst du nach den Kindern **gucken**?"
- "Kannst du nach den Kindern **schauen**?

  das einzige, was hier wirklich aus der Reihe tanzt, wäre
- "Kannst du nach den Kindern **anschauen**?"

der Satz ergibt hier keinen Sinn. Ansehen verwendet man üblicher weise mit Ich sehe etwas an bzw. wenn man fragt, ob sich eine andere Person etwas ansehen könne.